# Duplicate name of the authentication provider in Sign In page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I faced the issue where i get duplicate authentication provider in sign in page

[image]

any tips where the problem is and how i can solve it to use just ona as a default one ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem has been resolved. I found that solution to this problem is simply workaround. We need to open CA and add FBA to this same Web App and name it as a TEST then when we open the web site at Sign in page we will see two options Winsows claims and FBA then we need to go back to our Authentication provider section and unchcecked the FBA option. Go back to your Web App portal adres and Sing in page shouldnt pop up any more and Windows Claims should work fine already.